# Mysql query to return # of occurences for each distinct field

Tags: mysql

I have the following table, how would I go about returning the number of occurrences of each `id` that has `status=pass`

```
id  status
111 pass
111 fail
333 pass
222 pass
333 pass
222 fail
```

so that the result set would look like this

```
id  num_occurrences
111 1
222 1
333 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this::

```
 select id, count(id) as num_occurrences from table where status="pass" group by id
```

Comment: Your answer would be better if you could explain to the OP _why_ this is correct.

Answer (score -1):

The query could look like that

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS num_occurrences FROM tableName WHERE status = 'pass'
```

but there is one thing. The id is usually unique co you shouldnt call that columnname id